# Show default local image while url image is loading

Tags: wpf

I am a wpf newbie. In my wpf app, I have images that load from the web. To avoid gui blocking, I followed the approach as mentioned in  [How can I keep a WPF Image from blocking if the ImageSource references an unreachable Url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463852/how-can-i-keep-a-wpf-image-from-blocking-if-the-imagesource-references-an-unreac)

Works great. Issue is, until the image loads, gui doesn't honor dimensions properties set in the Image node. End result is kind of a 'resize' affect - initially the gui(elements) are of one size and 'readjust' once image is loaded.

I wish to make the load 'smooth'. I want to be able to specify a 'initial default' image. Something like [initial image in WPF Image Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973629/initial-image-in-wpf-image-control)

However I am not able to get it to work. May be something like below in ImageAsyncHelper(which is obviously wrong) :

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceUriProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SourceUri", typeof(Uri), typeof(ImageAsyncHelper), new PropertyMetadata
    {
        PropertyChangedCallback = (obj,e) =>
        {
            ((Image)obj).SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty,
                new Binding("DefaultUri")
                {
                    Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/blah/Images/Default.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                });

        }

        PropertyChangedCallback += (obj, e) =>
        {
            ((Image)obj).SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty,
              new Binding("VerifiedUri")
              {
                  Source = new ImageAsyncHelper { GivenUri = (Uri)e.NewValue },
                  IsAsync = true,
              });
        }
    });
```

What are my options?

Comment: Maybe you should get an image to WPF memory and you don't have to worry about rest.

Comment: Are you building a WPF control?  Are you binding to the image in your XAML?

Comment: You say you want to make the transition smooth.  Do you mean you want the initial image and fetched image to be the same size?  Are you planning on showing the default image until the real imaged is ready?

Comment: @WaltRitscher - I am binding to the image in XAML. Basically I want the initial image and fetched image same size. I want to show the default image until the real image is ready. Main reason I even started with the default image route is so as to prevent 'resize' of the layout after url image load. Default image is not a must. So fixed dimension wrapper around my image tag is ok with me. But not sure what to use. Also the layout is set to auto adjust on resize, so I am not sure how that works if I fix dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Image elements MinWidth and MaxWidth to the desired size.